# Proposal to resolve ambiguity of 'independent-researcher' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [independent-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher) tag has the following tag wiki excerpt:

> An independent researcher is not affiliated with any university or academic institution, and does not receive grants from any such institutions.

Many of the questions in the tag are consistent with this meaning. For example,

- [What to put in “affiliation” field when submitting paper without affiliation?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/what-to-put-in-affiliation-field-when-submitting-paper-without-affiliation)
- [Applying for research funding as an independent researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9611/applying-for-research-funding-as-an-independent-researcher)
- [Independent Research and institutional review boards?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15531/independent-research-and-institutional-review-boards)
- [How to get a .edu email address as an independent mathematician?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10415/how-to-get-a-edu-email-address-as-an-independent-mathematician)

However, other relate to the different meaning of "developing academic independence (from one's supervisor) as a research student or postdoc." For example:

- [To what extent should a professor give students freedom to do independent research?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24264/to-what-extent-should-a-professor-give-students-freedom-to-do-independent-resear)
- [Can a 3 years PhD make an independent researcher ? Or how many post-docs after PhD to be an independent researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/27691/can-a-3-years-phd-make-an-independent-researcher-or-how-many-post-docs-after-p)
- [How important is advisor's supervision for a Ph.D. student to be an independent researcher?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26220/how-important-is-advisors-supervision-for-a-ph-d-student-to-be-an-independent)

and several others.

This is a bad ambiguity, since people looking for questions about "unaffiliated researchers" are not the same people who are looking for questions about "research independence".

I therefore propose to:

1. Rename [independent-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher) to [unaffiliated-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unaffiliated-researcher) (using the magic mod tool, so it won't bump any questions)
2. Create a tag [research-independence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-independence) with the wiki excerpt

   > On developing academic independence (e.g., from one's supervisor) as a research student or postdoc.
3. Re-tag the mistagged questions in [independent-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher) that are really about [research-independence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-independence)

One thing I am not sure about is what to do with [independent-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher). I feel like it should be made a synonym of *something*, since people are likely to try and create it otherwise; but I'm not sure which it should be made a synonym of.

Answer (score 1):

I approve of the split into two tags. However, I feel like there might need to be [professional-development](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professional-development) instead of just [research-independence](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research-independence). I think it does a better job of encapsulating the goal.

Then, I would lump [independent-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-researcher) into [unaffiliated-researcher](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unaffiliated-researcher).

Comment: There is [tag:professional-development], and it's a synonym of [tag:career-path]. I think [tag:career-path] is getting much too broad, so I don't want to lump [tag:research-independence] in there too.

Comment: Why is it a synonym of [tag:career-path]? They're not the same thing _at all_.

Comment: Not in name or by definition, but in the way it was used, I seem to recall that it was. I think [tag:professional-development] might be too ambiguous for a tag name.

Comment: If we're thinking to do something more general, it should probably subsume [tag:soft-skills] too. I don't know what the right name is, though.